# Reference of NodeID and Parent in Engine log in CPLEX

Tags: cplex

I want to draw a tree from the information of nodes in engine log in CPLEX but i don't know which columns is number of node.
what is difference between the value of Node column and NodeID?
and what is the reference of Parent column?
I have the information in engine log that i can't draw tree with NodeID and Parent,because these two columns don't match with together. It means Parent columns didn't get information from NodeID.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/chLNr.jpg]

Comment: It looks like this question was crossposted [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=9e469c7b-a1a8-4a63-9c0f-b0ad4c8998ad).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [CPLEX user manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.studio.help/Optimization_Studio/topics/PLUGINS_ROOT/ilog.odms.studio.help/pdf/usrcplex.pdf?view=kc), the `NodeID` property `"specifies the node identifier"`.

Moreover, the CPLEX manual describes that the `parent` column then refers to the `NodeID` of the parent node.

In other words, each node refers to its parent node in the Branch and Bound tree by means of the `NodeID` of its parent. Hence, this information should make it possible to draw the Branch and Bound tree.

In contrast, the `Node` column simply orders the nodes in the order in which they are encountered. Hence, these numbers are always in ascending order.

Comment: I suppose that you were referring to this page of the manual: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/discr_optim/mip/para/52_node_log.html

Comment: That is indeed the page that I was referring to.

Comment: Thank you very much.
I thought NodeID  gets their values from Node column that is not true.
The order of NodeID is not clear. Why does it start with number 3 after root node?
For example I set best first for node selection but I can’t understand the order of selection and also  when I want to draw a tree according to NodeID and Parent, node3 and node4 are on the first depth and node2 and node1 are on the second depth. Why is that?

Comment: The numbers in the `Node` column are just the number of nodes processed so far. The numbers in the `NodeId` column are however unique ids for the node. These are completely unrelated. Moreover, you should not attach any meaning to those ids. The only thing that is guaranteed about these ids is that they are different for each node. There is no guarantee that they increment from parent to child. As you can see in the picture in Xavier's answer, the node with id 2 is a child of the node with id 3 (this is also explicitly stated in your log output).

Answer (score 0):

Building on @rowtricker's answer...

You should consider the `nodeID` as an opaque value, and not assume anything about it.  From the information above, you can reconstruct the tree as such:

```
            0
         /    \
        3      4
       / \    / \
      2   7  1   8
     /   /
    6   11   ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, i drew like this tree.